# Big white circle for point light

Tags: modeling, node-editor, light, lighting

I am trying to add a point light inside a lamp. Here is a snap of my node editor (for the glass):
[image]

But everytime I put the point light inside of the glass material, a big white spot forms.
[image]

I tried removing the reflection node and the transparent node but the white circle still doesn't go away. When I try putting other lamps, like the sun or hemi, the white dot doesn't appear. I want to keep the point light though because it illuminates better.Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's a big white dot is because the Point light size defaults to 10cm:

[image]

The only way to get "rid" of the dot is to make the point light smaller (which makes the dot smaller), but then you'll have to crank up the Strength to compensate.  If you crank it up too much you'll probably get a ton of fireflies.

The hard edges of the dot are because your glass has a roughness of 0.  If you set the roughness a little higher the edges of the dot will get softer.

What I would actually recommend is to model a light bulb (or candle flame) for your lamp, and set it to have an Emission texture.  I think that'll give you the best results in the end.

Answer (score 1):

That's the Point Lamp. It is invisible but it has to be reflected in glossy surfaces and it is visible to transmission rays so you see it through glass as well. You could turn off visibility for glossy and transmission rays in object's properties:

[image]

however this will defeat the purpose of the lamp as it will no longer illuminate glossy surfaces.

You can also make it smaller by adjusting the size property:

[image]

Keep in mind that very small light sources cause fireflies and more noise in renders.

I would recommend simulating the actual light source that would actually be visible in reality - that way it will not look weird.

Comment: haha, we must've been typing at the same time.